# Springboot app throws java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE for PoolBackedDataSource.close()

Tags: java, sql, spring, maven

I am writing a scheduler in my service that will make sync the database with quantities from another service once a day. The scheduler was working just fine until I suddenly started receiving

```
java.lang.Exception: DEBUG STACK TRACE for PoolBackedDataSource.close().
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.close(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:364)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at com.charter.spectrum.mobile.ias.update.MbosIASUpdateApplication.main(MbosIASUpdateApplication.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

I have tried to start fresh, by adding the necessary code one at a time but it isn't helping. It runs fine for sometime but starts giving this exception. I have taken in to consideration other responses I found on Google, but there are a very few responses available, none of which have been useful.
Can someone please help me understand where I maybe going wrong?
PS I am working with Java8, Spring, Maven, SQL

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think thiis is not the exact error, pls share your log right from the line where error has started to come.

Comment: Please add code snippets and full error stacktrace.

Comment: That's where the exception is starting. The gateway is getting started and out of nowhere I get this exception. But it is always I get this exception, sometimes it runs just fine

Comment: This Exception is just to show execution path for debug purposes. You can see that it's only a debug message. It shouldn't affect your functionality. If you want you can change your logging levels to skip these or simply ignore this.

Comment: As the message already states it is a **DEBUG STACKTRACE**. So you probably enabled debug logging (or automatically due to Spring Boot Devtools being used!) and upon restart (updated classes, html etc.) the project restarts and stops the current application. In short you can ignore this and if you want it removed, disable debug logging for the C3P0 connection pool (or switch to anohter pool like the default HikariCP which you apparently have overriden).